# Java programs in Linux Machine (UTC timezone) returning date in HDT timezone instead of UTC timezone

Tags: java, linux, date, timezone, java-7

I have a linux machine in UTC timezone.

```sh
[user@test packages]$ date +'%:z %Z'
+00:00 UTC
```

Running `cat /etc/localtime` also seems to indicate that my machine is in UTC timezone;

```sh
[user@test ~]$ cat /etc/localtime
f2UTCTZif2UTC
UTC0
```

However calling `logger.info(new Date())` in a application running tomcat under Java 1.7 returns something like Mon Oct 28 01:51:39 HDT 2019

This is very strange, so I created a simple Java program for testing:

```java
import java.util.Date;

class Test
{
        public static void main (String args[])
        {
                Date dt = new Date();
                System.out.println(dt);
        }
}
```

Compile and run it

```sh
[user@test]$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.211.x86_64/bin/javac Test.java
[user@test]$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.211.x86_64/bin/java Test
Mon Oct 28 02:08:49 HDT 2019
```

My question is why my Linux utility is return date in UTC format, and yet my Java apps are returning dates in HDT format (I don't even know what HDT is).

Since the app I'm maintaining is legacy, I can't use Joda Time or upgrade to Java8 or higher as this would meant lots of code changes.

Comment: What does `/etc/timezone` say? See [Check TimeZone on Linux host](https://cinhtau.net/2015/10/25/europebusingen-check-timezone-on-linux-host/)

Comment: **HDT** stands for **Hawaiian Daylight Time**.... is the machine located (or set up as it was) in Hawaii?

Comment: @Sterconium The machines are in a company data center, The machines by rule must be in UTC

Comment: @Andreas I tried to overwriting `/etc/localtime` with `/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC`. The machine a RedHat one doesn't have `/etc/timezone`

Comment: This is one of the points why there is `java.time` from Java 8. It will be a lot harder to get reliable dates and times using `java.util` than migrating to `java.time`. What does `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry());` print on the system that prints the timestamp in HDT? What does `System.out.println(ZoneId.systemDefault().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.getDefault()));` print?

Comment: Ok but this does not answer my question: are this machine (or set up as they were) in Hawaii?

Comment: @Sterconium The machines are somewhere in Texas, not Hawaii

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` or just `ZoneId`; both are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: An old-fashioned `Date` hasn’t got a time zone. But that it prints as `HDT` is a sign that the JVM’s time zone setting may be Hawaiian-Aleutian Time. You can check by printing `ZoneId.systemDefault()` and `System.getProperty("user.timezone")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fix it by doing the following:

- Run `ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/timezone` and
- Modify `/etc/sysconfig/clock`

I got the idea of looking at `/etc/sysconfig/clock` after reading this https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6456628

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Never use the legacy class `Date`.

- `Instant.now()`
  For current moment as seen in UTC.
- `ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Honolulu" ) )`
  For current moment as seen in a particular time zone.

> 2020-02-18T05:28:11.146726Z
>
> 2020-02-17T19:28:11.146726-10:00[Pacific/Honolulu]

## Details

Firstly, you should know that your `java.util.Date` is actually a moment in UTC but its `toString` method dynamically applies the JVM's current default time zone while generating the text. Very confusing. One of many reasons to **never use this class**.

`Date`, `Calendar`, and the other legacy date-time classes were supplanted by *java.time* years ago with the adoption of JSR 310.

## Avoid depending on default time zone

Using the *java.time* classes, you can easily write code that does not depend on a default time zone. You can specify your desired offset-from-UTC or time zone explicitly, whether that be UTC itself (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds) or a [time zone like `Pacific/Honolulu`](https://time.is/Honolulu).

### UTC

If you want to track a moment in UTC, use `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

The `Instant::toString` method generates text in standard ISO 8601 format. The formats defined by this standard are designed for data exchange.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> output: 2020-02-18T05:28:11.146726Z

The `Z` on the end means UTC, and is pronounced “Zulu”.

### Zoned

If you want to see that same moment by the wall-clock time used by the people in Hawaii, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `HDT` or `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Honolulu" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

The `ZonedDateTime::toString` method wisely extends the ISO 8601 format by appending the name of the time zone is square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/HYNcO7).

> outputZdt: 2020-02-17T19:28:11.146726-10:00[Pacific/Honolulu]

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).